# Create Small Database in Android for Remote Access by Multiple Users

Tags: java, android, database, server

New to android programming and want to save basic student information in a database. What is the easiest and simplest way to store this data so it can be accessed by multiple devices remotely at any time? I know that android supports sqlite but this seems to be only locally on one device. Any ideas or suggestions?Eventually want to publish application on google play and want users to be able to see students names in their class for each class.

Comment: Please note: ***Questions asking us to recommend ... a tool, software library ...  are off-topic for Stack Overflow*** - [Help Center](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're not interested in setting up and maintaining a remote server, Firebase is fast, free to get started, and operates in realtime:

https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/

Answer (score 0):

It seems you've answered your own question :) Place your relational database, such as MySQL, on a remote server. Create an API that performs CRUD operations on the database tables.

Then issue requests to the API in your android app: https://developer.android.com/training/volley/index.html

Comment: That still requires you to maintain your own server

Comment: Where in the OP does it state he doesn't wish to host own server?

Comment: That would probably in the description of "simple" and "easy" to not maintain any server or API code

Comment: *"It can be accessed by multiple devices remotely at any time"*. For those without the resources (hardware / money), one wouldn't run pay and run MySQL when you can use Firebase for free. That's all I'm getting at

Answer (score 0):

> Yea you basically answered your own, I highly recommend using retrofit2 for android for http requests.You’ll use annotations to describe HTTP requests, URL parameter replacement and query parameter support is integrated by default. Additionally, it provides functionality for custom headers, multipart request body, file uploads and downloads, mocking responses and much more.

[Here is great link to get started on your way to happy life:)](https://futurestud.io/tutorials/retrofit-getting-started-and-android-client)

Ideally you would want to create your server to handle request and give responses, and android client for those request, if you are going the custom route you probably want a node.js server, or php server. You can even use socket.io to spice things up for real time communication, or maybe some notification system from firebase. Firebase is awesome, it handle all the aforementioned.

For the database portion if you decide not to use Firebase, please do not Raw SQLite you will have nightmares, use something like Realm it is NoSQL ,fast and easy to perform database transactions.

Comment: Firebase is also great because it is real time, fast and mainly load balanced to handle multiple clients.

Comment: And you stressed multiple clients, so unless you want to create your web server with load balancing, I would suggest sticking with Firebase and the galore of API it provides, ranging from Databases. Messaging, Real time updates, security and load balancing.

Comment: Thank You! I think I'm going to try firebase first but this is also great to know!